# ASP.NET Impersonate in .NETFramework 2 VS .NETFrameWork 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, impersonation, .net-framework-version

We have an ASP.NET Site in .NetFramework 2 (with App Pool 2 Classic in IIS 7.5), We use mixed Authentication with `Basic Authenticate` and `Form Authenticate`.

The Configuration in IIS is:

[image]

And have specific user in Anonymous Authentication named: `Guest`.

When The user Login with another username like `Admin` we use impersonate:

```
string Token = GetSpecificTokenOfCurrentUser();
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity WinUser = (WindowsIdentity) HttpContext.Current.Application["User_"+Token];
WinUser.Impersonate();
```

So every thing is perfect until we upgrade website to .NetFramework 4 and add a lot of features in .NET 4 to website, and we figured we have a new Problem.

The problem is the user login with `Admin` And open some pages (3-4) all together in same time, like quickly opened in new tab, the User Not impersonated in some cases. Like the first page impersonated correctly to `Admin` but another pages not impersonated and still have `Guest` User.

This is so weird, we don't have any changes in Authentication Part. the changes is we upgrade to .NetFrameWork 4 and App Pool is .NetFrameWork 4 - Classic.

We have a test in .Net 2 Version Of Website. every thing is OK, but we change the App Pool to .NetFrameWork 4 and the problem was shown.

So The question is what changes happened in .NetFramework 4 App Pool to Impersonate?

Is there any thing we missed? any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I found Some points:

1- The Multi-Request behaves like Parallel processing, and as you know in classic mode we have some limitations with parallelism.

2- In Integrated mode we have some limitations in `Impersonate` Enable. The default behavior of Enable Impersonate is 500.24 Error: `Internal Server Error An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode"` if we want enable impersonate we need to add `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>` to `<system.webServer>` in web.config, So we don't get the error, but steel we have another limitation. The impersonate commands not worked in `Begin_Request`And in `AuthenticateRequest` Methods, anything else worked perfectly.

The [Breaking Changes for ASP.NET 2.0 applications running in Integrated mode on IIS 7.0](http://mvolo.com/breaking-changes-for-aspnet-20-applications-running-in-integrated-mode-on-iis-70/) is very good article in this case.

So the solution is

Move to Integrated mode (Need Add tag) And Use Impersonate in any other methods instead of `Begin_Request` or `AuthenticateRequest`.